# How long does it take to recover from a biopsy of a tendon?

Tags: tendons, recovery, biopsy

I wonder how long it takes to recover from a biopsy of a tendon.

E.g. *Zheng, Ming Hao, Paul Anderson, and Jerome Waddell. [Orthocell's Ortho-ATI: Tendon Regeneration](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Orthocell%27s+Ortho-ATI%3A+Tendon+Regeneration&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp=). Vol. 1. Jerome Waddell, 2014.,* propose to treat tendinopathies by extracting tendon samples  from the patient via minimally invasive biopsy, growing tenocytes, and reinjecting them back to the injured tendon.

Comment: Are we talking about in an otherwise healthy adult?  Peds can actually be faster, but geriatric (where I have little experience and this is more commonly done) tend to recover slower.

Comment: @AtlLED Yes, otherwise healthy adult. Let's say ~30 year-old male.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.